# SSHD Service on Windows Server 2012 R2 not showing

Tags: ssh, powershell, openssh, sftp, windows-server-2012-r2

I tried to install open-ssh on the windows server to test a script for sftp.
I followed [this guide](https://www.server-world.info/en/note?os=Windows_Server_2012&p=openssh).
After setting up the path and switching to the folder I ran from a admin power shell:
`.\install-sshd.ps1` -> 3 'SUCCESS'
`.\ssh-keygen.exe -A` -> Worked
`Get-Service | findstr ssh` -> 
`Stopped ssh-agent OpenSSH Authentification Agent`
`Stopped sshd OpenSSH SSH Server`
So I ran:
`Start-Serivce ssh` -> Failed to start service 'Open SSH Server (sshd)'.
I have no clue what to do next. Unser `services` sshd doesn't show either.

Comment: the name has changed to "ssh-agent" by OpenSSH Authentication Agent. Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

I'm following the same guide as you do, I'm also install the OpenSSH on Win Server 2012R2

In my case, the service name in `windows services` wasn't `sshd` but `OpenSSH SSH Server` and `OpenSSH Authentication Agent`[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qblFq.png).

And the command I use to start the service is `Start-Service sshd`

Comment: This is probably not an answer to the OP's question. OP probably used `Start-Service sshd` too - `Start-Serivce ssh` is obviously just a typo (two typos), as the command understood, what OP wanted => *"Failed to start service 'Open SSH Server (sshd)'."*

Comment: Oh, sorry, I'm answer the question about `Unser services sshd doesn't show either.` 
And I think he can find the service `OpenSSH SSH Server` in the services maybe and start it with the UI.

Comment: I do not think that the UI would work, when `Start-Service sshd` does not.